# Replace Image with cropped BitmapSource

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml

I have an Image on my wpf control 
and I am trying to generate croped part of it - this is ok more or less. 
I have used a codeproject solution to generate BitmapSource of croped image (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/CropAdorner.aspx) but when I am trying to 
replace current image with generated BitmapSource like this

```
imgCurrent.Source = generatedBitmapSource;
```

I see very strange behaviour (( 
I need an advice how to change current Image with new based on BitmapSource.

my XAML(there is nothing extraordinary - and by the right click I am trying to replace currentImage with croped):

```
<DockPanel Height="395" Width="926">
    <!--Went with a DockPanel here so that the image would always be centered in its parent control.-->
    <Image x:Name="imgCurrent" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MouseRightButtonDown="imgCurrent_MouseRightButtonDown"/>
</DockPanel>
```

right click:

```
  private void imgCurrent_MouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    { 
           generatedBitmapSource = _clp.BpsCrop();
           //this clears croping adonder
           AdornerLayer aly = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(_felCur);
           aly.Remove(_clp);
    //
       imageCurrent.Source = generatedBitmapSource;
    }
```

croping method (from codeproject):

```
public BitmapSource BpsCrop()
        {
            Thickness margin = AdornerMargin();
            Rect rcInterior = _prCropMask.RectInterior;

            Point pxFromSize = UnitsToPx(rcInterior.Width, rcInterior.Height);

            // It appears that CroppedBitmap indexes from the upper left of the margin whereas RenderTargetBitmap renders the
            // control exclusive of the margin.  Hence our need to take the margins into account here...

            Point pxFromPos = UnitsToPx(rcInterior.Left + margin.Left, rcInterior.Top + margin.Top);
            Point pxWhole = UnitsToPx(AdornedElement.RenderSize.Width + margin.Left, AdornedElement.RenderSize.Height + margin.Left);
            pxFromSize.X = Math.Max(Math.Min(pxWhole.X - pxFromPos.X, pxFromSize.X), 0);
            pxFromSize.Y = Math.Max(Math.Min(pxWhole.Y - pxFromPos.Y, pxFromSize.Y), 0);
            if (pxFromSize.X == 0 || pxFromSize.Y == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }
            System.Windows.Int32Rect rcFrom = new System.Windows.Int32Rect(pxFromPos.X, pxFromPos.Y, pxFromSize.X, pxFromSize.Y);

            RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(pxWhole.X, pxWhole.Y, s_dpiX, s_dpiY, PixelFormats.Default);
            rtb.Render(AdornedElement);
            return new CroppedBitmap(rtb, rcFrom);
        }
```

Comment: Can you describe what "strange behavior" do you get?

Comment: Can you show your cropping and right click method?

Comment: black square for example

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't have issue with your "BitmapSource of croped image"?  Can you for test purpose replace it with another valid Bitmap and try if it works.  If it works with another one, but not "BitmapSource of croped image" then maybe you have issue with creating "BitmapSource of croped image".